# Form freezes for x seconds when zipping a folder in C#

Tags: c#, zip, freeze

I have a windows form project in which I zip a folder. The form freezes for 3-4 seconds and then the operation is done.

```
private void ZipSafe(string p_FolderName, string p_ArchiveName)
{
    try
    {
        if (File.Exists(p_ArchiveName))
            File.Delete(p_ArchiveName);

        string[] l_DataSet = Directory.GetFiles(p_FolderName, "*.txt");
        using (ZipArchive l_Zip = ZipFile.Open(p_ArchiveName, ZipArchiveMode.Create))
        {
            foreach (string l_File in l_DataSet)
            {

                using (FileStream l_Stream = new FileStream(l_File, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Delete | FileShare.ReadWrite))
                {
                    ZipArchiveEntry l_ZipArchiveEntry = l_Zip.CreateEntry(Path.GetFileName(l_File), CompressionLevel.Optimal);
                    using (Stream l_Destination = l_ZipArchiveEntry.Open())
                    {
                        l_Stream.CopyTo(l_Destination);
                    }
                }
            }
            l_Zip.Dispose();
        }
    }
    catch (System.Exception e)
    {
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\**\Documents\ErrorZip.txt"))
        {
            string l = e.ToString();
            sw.WriteLine(l);
            sw.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

I call this function when clicking on a button. I have tried to use the debugger to understand what's going on here. The freeze happens during the second iteration of the for-each loop, for the following line of code:

```
l_Stream.CopyTo(l_Destination);
```

I know there has been a lot of post about zipping folders in c#, still I hope my question is relevant. Any help would be great, thank in advance guy.

Have a good day,
vbvx

Comment: Use a background worker?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Why does it freeze and can I prevent it from freezing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because you are using the UI thread to carry out the operation. You need to run the operation on another thread to leave the UI thread free (i.e. stopping your application from freezing).

try:

```
private void ZipSafe(string p_FolderName, string p_ArchiveName)
{
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
try
{
    if (File.Exists(p_ArchiveName))
        File.Delete(p_ArchiveName);

    string[] l_DataSet = Directory.GetFiles(p_FolderName, "*.txt");
    using (ZipArchive l_Zip = ZipFile.Open(p_ArchiveName, ZipArchiveMode.Create))
    {
        foreach (string l_File in l_DataSet)
        {

            using (FileStream l_Stream = new FileStream(l_File, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Delete | FileShare.ReadWrite))
            {
                ZipArchiveEntry l_ZipArchiveEntry = l_Zip.CreateEntry(Path.GetFileName(l_File), CompressionLevel.Optimal);
                using (Stream l_Destination = l_ZipArchiveEntry.Open())
                {
                    l_Stream.CopyTo(l_Destination);
                }
            }
        }
        l_Zip.Dispose();
    }
}
catch (System.Exception e)
{
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\**\Documents\ErrorZip.txt"))
    {
        string l = e.ToString();
        sw.WriteLine(l);
        sw.Close();
    }
}
}
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. It doesn't seem to help neither, and this morning the form never unfreezes so I guess it's something else? I cannot get the exception written down in my text file "ErrorZip.txt" neither.

Comment: In the end it's just that the sizes of the files I was compressing were super large. But I guess your remark is a good add anyway that's why it's the marked answer. Btw, I would have liked to have comments with downrate, it's easier to improve yourself when you understand what's wrong.